# Artificial feather badminton shuttles

Tags: equipment, badminton

I recently came to know about the animal cruelty involved in the making of real goose feather shuttles in most cases. So I am confused about the shuttles I use to play in club, they don't look like real feather. And I don't want to buy or play with real feather shuttles. So I want to ask, is there any think like artificial feather shuttles? I read about faux feather shuttles but I don't know what faux feather means.

Comment: I think Faux feathers are used in archery for arrows for the same reasons. they are fake feathers no doubt. often using thin strands of hair or plastic instead of bird feathers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of "faux" is:  **artificial or imitation; fake** so if you don't want to play with real feather shuttles, you can buy the "faux feather" shuttles and be safe to know that they aren't real feathers, but fake, imitation feathers, made to look or feel or act like real feathers, but they are not real.

[Definition of "Faux"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faux)